# VBA chart with multiple categories

Tags: vba, charts

Can anybody help with the following - I have a large dataset with 37000 ish records. The data has a major category - Basin Name and a subcategory - Play name. Plays can be in several basins, and bains can have many plays. I want a script that can group all of the similar values together, and plot a chart (x,y scatter) for each set of similar data. Please see the example below.

I'm completely new to VBA so I don't know if this can be done.....

Comment: Which example? If this is MS Access, have a look at crosstabs.

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of it. you'll be best summarising the data with a Pivot Table, and then creating a chart from that.

Have a read up online about Pivot Tables, they'll change your life ;-)